# signup post request is not been sent to the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

When i try to have a post request to server the details is not being updated and showing 404 response the request from the signup page should be headed over to backend with the post request and should be stored in mongodb.
signup page:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Signup = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post(`/signup`, { username, password });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Signup</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Signup</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

backend code:

```
// server.js
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
});

// User schema and model
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

app.use(express.json());
app.get("/signup" ,(req,res)=>{
    res.send("hello");
})
// Signup route
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username already exists' });
    }
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const user = new User({ username, password: hashedPassword });
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User created successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

i tried changing the hosts but didnt work and expecting to get the post request to work fine.

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the complete URL being requested in the AJAX POST request?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/signup this was the url in the post request

Comment: According to the code shown, the server is running on port 5000, not 3000.  If your page is being served from a different server instance then you'd need to use an absolute URL (to include the port number) to access a separate server.